# Finding Trace of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Select the trace of the Upper triangular Matrix of below

$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 7\\-2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

I began by doing $R_2=2R_2+R_1$ which gives me

$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 7\\0 & 13\end{bmatrix}$

But answer is given to be 10.5

And the U decomposition I found to be

$\begin{bmatrix}4 & 7\\0 & \frac{13}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

Where I went Wrong?

Comment: Usually you don't scale the row you are modifying, you just add a multiple of the pivot row. So it would be $R_2 \gets R_2 + \mathit{something} \cdot R_1$ instead of $R_2 \gets \mathit{something} \cdot R_2 + R_1$.

Comment: ohhhhh. Thanks :)